# Is there a way to use config-default.xml globally in Oozie?

Tags: oozie

From the [documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4_Parameterization_of_Workflows), `config-default.xml` must be presented in the workflow workspace.

```
- /workflow.xml
- /config-default.xml
|
- /lib/ (*.jar;*.so)
```

### The problem

I've created a custom Oozie action and try to add default values for `retry-max` and `retry-interval` to all the custom actions.
So my `workflow.xml` will look like this:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="wf-name">
<action name="custom-action" retry-max="${default_retry_max}" retry-interval="${default_retry_interval}">
</action>
```

`config-default.xml` file contains the values of `default_retry_max` and `default_retry_interval`.

### What I've tried

1. Putting `config-default.xml` to every workflow workspace. This works, but the problem is there will be this file everywhere.
2. Setting `oozie.service.LiteWorkflowStoreService.user.retry.max` and `oozie.service.LiteWorkflowStoreService.user.retry.inteval` also works, but it would affect all action types.
3. I've also looked at [Global Configurations](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a19_Global_Configurations), but it doesn't solve this problem.

I think there should be a way to put `config-default.xml` to `oozie.libpath` and only those workflows that use this `libpath` will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is unfortunately no clean way to do it.

You might be interested in this recently created feature request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-3179

The only thing that worked for me was to begin the workflow with a shell step that uses a script stored in hdfs. This script holds the centralized configuration. The script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "oozie.use.system.libpath=true"
echo "hbase_zookeeper_quorum=localhost"
.. etc other system or custom variables ..
```

Yes, the script simply prints the variables to the stdout.
Let's say the shell step action is called "global_config". All following steps are able to get the variables using following syntax:

```
${wf:actionData('global_config')['hbase_zookeeper_quorum']}
```

HTH...