# How to increase oozie shell memory container globally

Tags: bigdata, oozie

I am facing some issues like physical memory is out of memory. 
When I add below configs to workflow

```
  <property>
    <name>oozie.mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>6144</value> <!-- for example -->
  </property>
```

it works fine, I just wanted to know any other place apart from workflow where we can add this configs like global level of hadoop configs.

Comment: Which version of Oozie are you using?? In V4.x the prefix for properties targeted to the "launcher" was `oozie.launcher.`

Comment: AFAIK the `config-default.xml` (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220293/is-there-a-way-to-use-config-default-xml-globally-in-oozie ) and `<global>` tricks won't work for a Shell action, which is an "extension" (no feature parity with MapReduce or Java)